# Fail to use load Image in p5.jg

Tags: html, loadimage

When I use the HTML preview in *Atom*, everything looks fine. However, when I open the HTML file in Safari / Chrome, the page shows a word "loading" only. I think it is stuck in the `preload()` function. How should I fix the problem?

```
function preload()
{
  img  = loadImage("image/source.png");
}

function draw() 
{
  image(img,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Please add more details this info is not enough

Comment: Grammar and formatting fixes